# Plesk returning 401 POSTs to wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron, WooCommerce Webhooks pending

Tags: wordpress, cron

A server on Plesk is returning 401 errors on POSTs to /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=STRING_OF_NUMBERS when WooCommerce webhooks are firing. This is keeping all webhooks as “pending.” How can I prevent this?

Comment: Same problem, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking file permission of cron scripts.
This could happenned beacause plesk has no right to execute the files.